# Change AndroidManifest.xml on Ionic v3.7.0

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using v3.7.0 and I want to change the AndroidManifest.xml when I build my app. Currently I have tried changing the `my-project-path/config.xml` file adding the the following lines:

Option a.

```
<widget>
    <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
</widget>
```

Option b.

```
<widget>
     <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
</widget>
```

Then I do:

```
$ ionic cordova build android
```

And I was expecting the following change on `my-project-path/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I get the same result as without adding the preference settings:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I apply the desired effect to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to do here? use case?

Comment: I want to set the value of android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" using the config.xml file on the root of the project.

Answer (score 13):

I found how to do it. If your Cordova version is above 6.4.0 you can use the tag `<edit-config>` (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) and I think that if you are using the latest version of Ionic probably you'll have a Cordova version above 6.4.0 (I have 7.1).

So the way to make the desired change that I wanted I had to set the `my-project-path/config.xml` file as follows:

```
<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
      <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </edit-config>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Check that the widget has a new attribute.

With this change when I build the Android version the manifest `my-project-path/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The new pathfile is not my-project-path/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml, but my-project-path/platform/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/AndroidManifest.xml.   Also found one in another path: /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

It looks like **AndroidManifest.xml** is something that's get derived from **config.xml** and not something you would want to directly edit.

I would edit **config.xml** and sections of it are reflected into the various AndroidManifest.xml used for building Android APKs